# Maven - Depend on assembled zip

Tags: maven, zip, pom.xml, maven-assembly-plugin, maven-dependency-plugin

I'm trying to have a **Project B** pull down (and unpack) a ZIP built by **Project A** and deployed to a remote repository.

The ZIP is created and attached using the `maven-assembly-plugin`, with packaging type `pom`:

```xml
<artifactId>project-a</artifactId>
<name>ZIP</name>
<description>Used by Project B</description>
<packaging>pom</packaging>

...

<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <id>distribution-package</id>
      <phase>package</phase>
      <goals>
        <goal>single</goal>
      </goals>
      <configuration>
        <descriptors>
          <descriptor>src/main/assembly/scripts.xml</descriptor>
        </descriptors>
        <tarLongFileMode>gnu</tarLongFileMode>
      </configuration>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

Attempting to pull it down from **Project B**'s pom with the `maven-dependency-plugin`:

```xml
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <id>copy-scripts</id>
      <phase>package</phase>
      <goals>
        <goal>copy</goal>
      </goals>
      <configuration>
        <outputDirectory>${basedir}/target/staging</outputDirectory>
        <stripVersion>true</stripVersion>
        <artifactItems>
          <artifactItem>
            <groupId>...</groupId>
            <artifactId>...</artifactId>
            <version>...</version>
            <overWrite>true</overWrite>
            <type>zip</type>
          </artifactItem>
        </artifactItems>
      </configuration>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

fails with: `[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project ...: Could not resolve dependencies for project group:artifact:pom:version: Could not find artifact group:project-a:zip:version in nexus (http://...:8081/nexus/content/groups/public) -> [Help 1]`

I would assume this is because I specified **Project A**'s packaging as `pom` and not `zip`, however I can't specify **Project A** as packaging type `zip` because it results in:

```xml
[ERROR]     Unknown packaging: zip @ line 13, column 13
```

Am I doing something wrong here or is this simply not possible?
I just have a bunch of files that I want to bundle up into an artifact and allow multiple other projects to download and unpack them for use. Open to different suggestions...

I've also checked to make sure that the assembled zip is indeed in the nexus.

**UPDATED WITH ANSWER**

For anyone else's benefit, what I was missing is that the `<classifier>` of the dependency has to match the `<id>` of the assembly. Notice where `thisistheattachedartifactsclassifier` is specified in the following files.

scripts.xml (Project A):

```xml
<assembly>
  <id>thisistheattachedartifactsclassifier</id>
  <formats>
    <format>zip</format>
  </formats>

  <fileSets>
    <fileSet>
      <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
      ...
    </fileSet>
  </fileSets>
</assembly>
```

pom.xml (Project B):

```xml
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <id>copy-scripts</id>
      <phase>package</phase>
      <goals>
        <goal>copy</goal>
      </goals>
      <configuration>
        <outputDirectory>${basedir}/target/staging</outputDirectory>
        <stripVersion>true</stripVersion>
        <artifactItems>
          <artifactItem>
            <groupId>...</groupId>
            <artifactId>...</artifactId>
            <version>...</version>
            <classifier>thisistheattachedartifactsclassifier</classifier>
            <overWrite>true</overWrite>
            <type>zip</type>
          </artifactItem>
        </artifactItems>
      </configuration>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

Comment: If anyone's wondering why there's a need to do something like this, here's one such maven dependency packaged in this annoying way: http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.jcabi/DynamoDBLocal

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Welcome to Stack Overflow :).

You are on the right way. Your real problem is using a zip.

The following configuration is ok and work great for me. It's an old one (2 years ago), and I'm not sure that match the best practices. But I Know that's working.

This allow me to share some resources between projects, especially for unit tests.

### Zip Project :

**pom.xml**

```xml
<groupId>com.mycompany</groupId>
<artifactId>cfg_dev</artifactId>
<version>1.1.0</version>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>cfg-main-resources</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>single</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <configuration>
                        <descriptors>
                            <descriptor>/src/main/assembly/resources.xml</descriptor>
                        </descriptors>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

**Assembly descriptor :** 
It will produce this artifact : cfg_dev-1.1.0-resources.zip
Please, note that

1. this is a zip archive
2. the "classifier" is resources (like assembly name)

   resources
     
       zip
     
     false
     
       
         src/main/resources

### Main Project :

**pom.xml**

Please, note that

1. this depends on a zip archive
2. the dependency "classifier" is resources (like previous assembly name)

   ```xml
   <!-- Unit test dependency -->
   <dependency>
       <groupId>com.mycompany</groupId>
       <artifactId>cfg_dev</artifactId>
       <version>${project.version}</version>
       <classifier>resources</classifier>
       <type>zip</type>
       <scope>test</scope>
   </dependency>

     ....

   <build>
     <testResources>
       <!-- Ressources habituelles  -->
       <testResource>
           <directory>src/test/resources</directory>
           <filtering>true</filtering>
       </testResource>
       <!-- Unzipped resources from cfg_dev  -->
       <testResource>
           <directory>${project.build.directory}/test-resources</directory>
           <filtering>true</filtering>
       </testResource>
   </testResources>

   <plugins>

       <!-- Unzip shared resources -->
           <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
           <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
           <executions>
               <execution>
                   <id>unpack-cfg-test-resources</id>
                   <goals>
                       <goal>unpack-dependencies</goal>
                   </goals>
                   <phase>generate-test-resources</phase>
                   <configuration>
                       <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/test-resources</outputDirectory>
                       <includeArtifactIds>cfg_dev</includeArtifactIds>
                       <includeGroupIds>${project.groupId}</includeGroupIds>
                       <excludeTransitive>true</excludeTransitive>
                       <excludeTypes>pom</excludeTypes>
                       <scope>test</scope>
                   </configuration>
               </execution>
           </executions>
       </plugin>
     </plugins>
   ```

I hope this is clear and that will help you :)

Comment: Thanks. A little fuzzy, but you got me in the right direction. For anyone else's benefit, what did it was the `id` of the assembly in the descriptor XML is used to identify the specific artifact as it's `classifier`.

Comment: assembly `name` ? you mean `id`.

Comment: Please note that it is a lot easier to use goal [`unpack`](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/unpack-mojo.html) and specify an `<artifact>` or `<artifactItems>`.  (As opposed to your using `unpack-dependencies` and excluding transitivity and including the specific dependency you need.)

Answer (score 5):

An alternate approach could be to give up on zipping entirely, use the standard Maven lifecycle to pack your files as resources in a jar file and access them from your other projects via classpath.

Unless you have specific packing requirements (including, excluding, etc.) this would require no additional configuration: just put your stuff in your project's `src/main/resources` directory.

This approach has the added benefit of working unchanged when invoked from within an IDE such as Eclipse.

Answer (score 3):

If you ever want to do something like this from the command line (e.g. from a script without having to write a `pom.xml` file), here's the way to do it...

You can either specify the individual properties:

```
mvn dependency:copy -DgroupId=org.apache.maven -DartifactId=maven-core -Dversion=2.2.1 -Dpackaging=zip -Dclassifier=thisistheattachedartifactsclassifier
```

Or specify them all in one `artifact` parameter:

```
mvn dependency:copy -Dartifact=org.apache.maven:maven-core:2.2.1:zip:thisistheattachedartifactsclassifier
```

With the latter, it is important to keep the `classifier` at the end, after the `packaging/type` attribute. Like this: `-Dartifact=groupId:artifactId:version:type:classifier`

You can also optionally specify the target directory using the `-DoutputDirectory=<directory>` parameter if required.