# Configuration required to Run Maven project with Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, maven, configuration

I have a Maven project in SVN with *trunk\Config\TestProjConfig* folder having all the XML configuration files and all Java code is in *trunk\JavaSource\TestProj*. When I check out to my local Eclipse there are 2 projects created one for TestProjConfig and one for TestProj.

How do I test this project? Do I have to edit the build path to make a connection between the two projects? Do I have to write a main class which accesses the AppContext file to invoke the Spring injections?

Note:I have the m2eclipse plugin in Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why you separated XML configuration from Java sources. It could be a good practice only if you want to reuse your conf in other project, but in this case, I'm not sure that's suitable.

### Solution 1

Move all your xml config into JavaSource\TestProj\src\main\resources

If you really don't have to share your configuration or don't have any legacy / corporate / mysterious reason, you should not separate them.

### Solution 2

If you REALLY want to separate them, put them in a zip with an assembly, and add a dependency from TestProj to TestProjConfig.
Here an example : [Maven - Depend on assembled zip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12298178/maven-depend-on-assembled-zip/12299646#12299646)