# Include maven dependecny with wrong name

Tags: java, maven, dependencies, zip

I want to include artifact `my_groupid:my_artifact:1.1` into my project, but it has wrong name in maven repository. The repository structure is:

```
my_groupid
    my_artifact
        1.1
            my_artifact-1.1-config.jar
            my_artifact-1.1-config.jar.md5
            my_artifact-1.1-config.jar.sha1
            my_artifact-1.1.pom
            my_artifact-1.1.pom.md5
            my_artifact-1.1.pom.sha1
```

my_artifact-1.1.pom conatins:

```
<project xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
        <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
        <groupId>my_groupid</groupId>
        <artifactId>my_artifact</artifactId>
        <packaging>pom</packaging>
        <version>1.1</version>
        <dependencies/>
</project>
```

The artifact my_artifact-1.1-config.jar contains just two XML files in the root and seems like a simple zip.

I've tried `build-helper-maven-plugin` like [Maven - Depend on assembled zip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12298178/maven-depend-on-assembled-zip) but I can't specify type `zip`. Simple

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>my_groupid</groupId>
        <artifactId>my_artifact</artifactId>
        <version>1.1</version>
        <type>jar</type>
    </dependency>
```

is not working because of wrong artifact name in repository.

How to include this artifact to access my XMLs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the "config" part seems to be the deployment *classifier*. I would specify a classifier field in the dependency setup:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>my_groupid</groupId>
        <artifactId>my_artifact</artifactId>
        <version>1.1</version>
        <classifier>config</classifier>
</dependency>
```